# How to use t.test function for two vectors containing nan value

Tags: r

Does someone have the solution for this problem:

```
student1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA,n,1))

for (j in 1:n){
  student1[j]<-if(t.test(matrice_tas2[j,], 
         matrice_tas1[j,],var.equal = FALSE)$p.value <=0.05){student1[j] <- 1.}
         else {student1[j] <- 0.}  
}
```

> Error in t.test.default(matrice_tas2[j, ], matrice_tas1[j, ], var.equal = FALSE) : 
>     nombre d'observations 'y' insuffisant

How do I calculate a t test when there are some na.values in matrice_tas2, matrice_tas1?

Comment: Please provide some sample data so people can replicate your problem. This appears to be failing due to an insufficient number of observations in your matrice_tas2 object.

Comment: Cool. I give a simple example:

Comment: All of the entries of you matrix are missing (NA). Is that what you want?

Comment: The error is saying you don't have enough observations. How many are not missing in each column when you get the error?